# Issues Compiling Double Precision fortran programs on Apple M2

Tags: macos, gcc, gfortran, arm64

I'm trying to load and compile several of Mark Drela's programs (Xfoil, AVL) on my new M2 macbook pro. I've compiled these before on intelx86 but I'm running into several very curious issues on apple silicon.

For instance, when I compile avl (https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/) and its dependencies in single-precision, everything appears to work just fine. However, when I compile double precisions versions of these libraries and programs (plotlib, eispack, and avl itself). The program compiles fine, and loading the hershey.avl test case from runs I can look at the geometry just within avl.

[When I attempt to execute avl through the oper menu, I get the following response:

.OPER (case 1/1)   c>  x
Building normalwash AIC matrix...
Factoring normalwash AIC matrix...
Building source+doublet strength AIC matrix...
Building source+doublet velocity AIC matrix...
Building bound-vortex velocity matrix...

iter d(alpha)   d(beta)    d(pb/2V)   d(qc/2V)   d(rb/2V)   LEflap
1   Infinity   Infinity -0.225+308 -0.000E+00  0.000E+00 -0.000E+00
Cannot trim.  Alpha too large.  a =                  Infinity

.OPER (case 1/1)   c>

AVL   c>  quit
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_INVALID_FLAG IEEE_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO IEEE_OVERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG

I'm still investigating but I'm a bit lost since single-precision compiles and works just fine.

Once you compile avl, the following input sequence should reproduce my current error

```
./avl

load ../runs/hershey.avl
oper
x
```

I compile using gcc and gfortran on a 2023 macbookpro with an M2 Pro chip running macOS Sonoma.

Gfortran flags are -m64 -fdefault-real-8 -O -fallow-argument-mismatch
If there issues i can send out makefiles

Comment: If one does not know what they're doing, the `-fdefault-real-8` is quite dangerous.  If you need the `-fallow-argument-mismatch` option, it can also lead to various hard to debug problems.  At a minimum, you should be compiling with the `-Wall -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow` options and fixing any gotcha.  Finally, the `-fdefault-real-8 -fallow-argument-mismatch` are not a panacea for porting from single precision to double precision.

Comment: You are using the [tag:compiler-errors] but you are not showing any such error being reported. There is not nearly enough information given by I agree you are playing with wire. You may be better with `-freal-4-real-8  -finteger-4-integer-8` or you may not, depending what happens in the code. But you absolutely can **not** just ignore problems with `-fallow-argument-mismatch`. With that you are just getting what you ask for.

Comment: Understood on the `-fallow-argument-mismatch`. Mark sent me the makefile with that flag and I've been running with it since. I'm clearly not an expert in Fortran, but afaik it was added to suppress errors and warnings due to various F77 features being deprecated. I agree `-fdefault-real-8` must be the source because single-precision compiles just fine

Comment: Be careful about how exactly you are compiling the stuff. I tried compiling AVL and found there are some pre-existing binaries in the archive on the website  and the Makefiles created libraries with a different filenames than what was then linked in the final Makefile. It all needs manual tweaks to work. Perhaps you have some other Makefiles. Without the exact complete [mre] it is basically impossible to answer this. In the end I am not getting your results. I am getting some numbers, most of them being zero.

Comment: When trying to specify some nonzero alpha, which I do not know if I am doing right, I am getting some infinities and NaNs. Note that I used the single precision build of eispack because using the `-fdefault-real-8` there was suspicious. It uses `DOUBLE PRECISION` inside. It would certainly deserve a better  build procedure.

Comment: Yeah the build procedures are a mess and I'm trying to clean them up because it's getting harder to maintain. I've talked with Mark about it (I'm his grad student) but he operates on a fix-as-needed basis for his own work. I'll set up an example that I use on this M2 mac, which is the only platform I've ever had issues on. I've traced the current error to LUDCMP in asetup.f